# Add a new User for the database in mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb

I want to add a new user to newly created database and if this user exists then i will connect to that database.
My code is:

public CreateDatabaseOperationResult CreateDatabase(string databaseName,string username,string password, MongoServer server)
        {

```
        CreateDatabaseOperationResult createDatabaseOpResult = new CreateDatabaseOperationResult();
         string message = null;
         MongoCredentials credentials = new MongoCredentials(username, password);
         MongoUser user = new MongoUser(credentials, false);
         try
         {
             if (IsDatabaseNameValid(databaseName, out message))
             {
                 if (server.DatabaseExists(databaseName, admincredentials) == true)
                 {
                     createDatabaseOpResult.Database = server.GetDatabase(databaseName, credentials);
                     MongoUser tempuser = createDatabaseOpResult.Database.FindUser(username);
                     if (tempuser.Equals(user))
                     {

                         //createDatabaseOpResult.DatabaseExists = true;
                         createDatabaseOpResult.IsOperationSuccessfull = false;
                         throw new ArgumentException("Database Already exist with different set of credentials ");
                     }
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     createDatabaseOpResult.Database = server.GetDatabase(databaseName, credentials);
                     createDatabaseOpResult.Database.AddUser(user);
                     //createDatabaseOpResult.DatabaseExists = false;

                 }

                 createDatabaseOpResult.IsOperationSuccessfull = true;
             }
         }
         catch (MongoQueryException ex)
         {
             createDatabaseOpResult.Error = ex;
         }
         //catch (MongoAuthenticationException ex)
         //{
         //    createDatabaseOpResult.Error = ex;
         //}
         catch (MongoException ex)
         {
             createDatabaseOpResult.Error = ex;
         }
         catch (ArgumentException ex)
         {
             createDatabaseOpResult.Error = ex;
         }


        return createDatabaseOpResult;

    }
```

When i use the existing database it connects to that database but when i try to add new use Database.AddUser gives error 'invalid credentials for this database'
Please see the error and reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most people use the mongo shell to add and remove users, but if you really want to do it in C# the trick is to use the right credentials depending on what you are trying to do. Assume you have the following two sets of credentials, one for the admin database and one for regular databases:

```
var adminCredentials = new MongoCredentials("myadminusername", "myadminpassword", true);
var userCredentials = new MongoCredentials("myusername", "myuserpassword");
```

Note that when creating the adminCredentials you *must* pass true to the admin parameter.

To test if a database exists requires admin credentials:

```
if (server.DatabaseExists("mydatabase", adminCredentials))
{
    // database exists
}
```

To add a user requires admin credentials:

```
var myDatabaseWithAdminCredentials = server.GetDatabase("mydatabase", adminCredentials);
if (myDatabaseWithAdminCredentials.FindUser("myusername") == null)
{
    myDatabaseWithAdminCredentials.AddUser(userCredentials);
}
```

Normally you use regular user credentials to work with a database:

```
var myDatabaseWithUserCredentials = server.GetDatabase("mydatabase", userCredentials);
var count = myDatabaseWithUserCredentials.GetCollection("mycollection").Count();
```

Also, keep in mind that each database can have any number of users, so you don't really need to be checking whether the database already exists with a different set of credentials.